# accessing values stored in multidimensional array

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array

I'm wondering..is there a way to easily acces a value which is stored in an multidimensional array. I provided an example:

```
var arrayOfTwoArrays = [[2,3,4], [5,6,7]]
arrayOfTwoArrays[0,2]       //error saying:  Extra argument in call
```

arrayOfTwoArrays[0,2] should return (if this worked) value 4. This is not happening and I'm getting an error. The Apple documentation models multidimensional array as a linear array, but I don't want the extra work.

Comment: `arrayOfTwoArrays[0][2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array of arrays is not quite the same thing as a multidimensional array (for example, the inner arrays can be of different sizes).  So to get values from the inner array, first fetch it, and then subscript it:

```
arrayOfTwoArrays[0][2]
```

Incidentally, if your intent was to get the last element of the first array, and the size of the arrays can vary and sometimes be empty, you could write it like this:

```
if let x = arrayOfTwoArrays.first?.last {
    // use x
}
```

which would account for the possibility of empty arrays.  You could then add an `else` to handle errors, or `??` to provide defaults, if this is a possibility you want specific handling for.